# Cannot add a new computer to gatling database page

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, gatling

I am cannot find the the computer I created in the gatling computers database.  I did the following:

1. Went to http://computer-database.gatling.io/computers
2. select 'add the new computer button'
3. add add new computer details
4. selected 'create this computer'
5. returned back the the homepage and got a confirmation that my new computer was created
6. Entered my computer into the 'filter my computer search box'

Could not find my freshly created computer.

If anyone has had this problem, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Our demo app is read only.
You can easily guess what some people can do (and did) with anonymous write access on a public facing application.

Comment: I will tell the the gatling tutor to update his course for this very reason.    Thank you for answering.